# After Win8 installed cannot boot from USB

Tags: boot, usb, bios

I installed Windows 8.1 and subsequent to that I cannot boot off of a USB stick. Even the USB stick that I used to install Windows 8.1 won't boot. i.e. I know that USB stick is bootable because I just installed Win 8.1 from it.

I've checked the BIOS settings and moved everything around to try and get a USB boot to take priority but no luck.

It looks like the Win 8.1 installation changed the BIOS. In the Hard Disk Boot Priority list there is a new "Bootable Add-in Cards" option and previously that option wasn't there. Instead there was an option that explicitly listed USB-something but that's now gone.

Ideas?

EDIT: There's also an option in the BIOS to reset or restore it. I haven't tried doing that yet. Would that impact Win 8.1 being able to boot?

Comment: Is your BIOS in legacy BIOS mode, or is in an EFI mode?  Have you  tested the USB stick on another computer to confirm it's still bootable?

Comment: Yes, USB stick is bootable on another computer. I don't think my BIOS has the option for EFI mode. It's the standard BIOS that came with the box, a Shuttle XPC from about 3 or 4 years ago.

Comment: Stumbled across this old question that never received an answer.  Can you update us on the status?  Ever get it solved?  If not, it seems like the kind of problem that would likely have been overtaken by events.  Do you still need a solution?